# highcharts not showing the `column` bar

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm trying to showing chart, but it is not showing the `column` bar . I don't see any error for my browser console, below is my script

```
$('#complete_chart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    margin: 75,
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: false,
                        alpha: 10,
                        beta: 25,
                        depth: 70
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Performance',
                    style: {
                            fontSize: '18px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                subtitle: {
                  text: 'Complete',
                  style: {
                            fontSize: '15px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        depth: 25
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
              
                exporting: { 
                    enabled: false 
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ["25","35","23","36","34"]           
                  },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                      var s = '<b>'+ this.point.project_name +'</b>';            
                      return s;     
                    }
                  },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Report Data',
                    data: [{"name":"Progress 1","val":100},{"name":"Progress 1","val":-165},{"name":"Progress 1","val":-1233},{"name":"Progress 1","val":-1114},{"name":"Progress 1","val":-175}],
                    shadow : true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#045396',
                        align: 'center',
                        formatter: function() {
                        
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.val, 0);
                        }, // one decimal
                        y: 0, // 10 pixels down from the top
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
```

did i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plotting for y axis data in `series.data` is `y` and not `val`. For eg :

```
[{"name":"Progress 1","y":100}...]
```

Changing it must provide you visibility for columns in column chart.
reference : https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#the-data-in-a-series